# According to researchers, which are the old and new mantras of the Vedic Samhitas?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, yajur-veda, sama-veda, research

**Please note:** This question seeks to gain a collation of diverse views of  Purvapakshis i.e. indologists as well as Indian researchers (like R.L. Kashyap) on the Samhitas, who actually aim to date the apaurusheya Veda and call some parts of Samhitas as interpolated or late additions. The focus of the question will be more towards the Rigveda.

---

The [Rigveda](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajurveda) is said to contain some of the oldest vedic mantras and has been “dated” to around 1500 BCE. The structure of the Rigveda comprises 10 mandalas or books, each containing suktams further containing a total of around 10,000 verses.

Thereafter comes the [Yajurveda](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajurveda) which is supposed to contain prose mantras as well. “Dated” to around 1200 BCE along with the Samaveda, it is divided into Krishna and Shukla respectively.

The next is the [Samaveda](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaveda#:%7E:text=The%20Samaveda%20consists%20of%201%2C549,are%20repeated%20more%20than%20once) supposed to be contemporaneous to the Yajurveda containing a total of 1,875 mantras (of which 1,549 are unique and others are repeated) taken entirely from the Rigveda, except for 75 of them.

I have read a few articles, as per which, some parts of the Rigvedic Samhita are newer (not necessarily interpolations) and some parts are very ancient. As per it, half the Mandalas were new and the other half were old. An example being, the 3rd Mandala is considered old, but the 9th Mandala is relatively new.

For the Yajurveda, it is stated that the Taittiriya Samhita is older than the Vajasaneyi.

**Question**

**Rigveda-** I would like to know the views of various researches on which parts of the Rigvedic Samhita are considered as old and which parts as new. The basis for such a distinction, as well as the difference in deities of the new and old parts.

**Yajurveda-** Alongside, I’d like their views on the older mantras vs the newer mantras, the reason, which of them are more in prose vs metered form; and if possible, the difference in deities of the older and newer mantras, if any. Especially with regard to the Taittiriya Samhita.

**Samaveda-** A comment on the ancientness of the unique Samavedic mantras. And a comment on whether the mantras adopted from the Rigveda pertain to the older or newer parts of it. Difference in deities in older or newer parts, if any.

I would like more emphasis on the Rigveda, considering that it is the oldest text and both Yajus and Sama derive mantras from it.

Please also give examples of mantras in Sanskrit with English translation to explain.

Comment: The Rishis in the Vedas themselves talk about "new" versus "old" hymns. Look at what this hymn from the krishna yajur veda says: 1.1.14.1 - "athA somasya prayatI yuvabhyAm **indrAgnI stomam janayAmi navyam**", the part in bold means, "I create a new stotram for indra and agni".

Comment: The rishis have said statements like that throughout all the four Vedas. The rishis say, "I created this mantra or hymn", whereas the prophets of other religions say, "God is speaking this through me", or "I am the voice of God". If the Vedas were truly "apaurusheya", the rishis would have mentioned it and said something like that. Also note that I am a follower of the krishna yajur veda and I believe in the authority of the Vedas since they were authored by the rishis based on their spiritual experiences.

Comment: @Ikshvaku yes even I believe the authority of the Veda. Even if I didn’t believe it, the authority of the true Veda exists and if one denies it, it’s pakhanda matam. And what you’re saying, is precisely one of the reasons of asking this question. I would like  a bifurcation of new and old hymns to see whether there are changes in deities, changes in language etc.

Comment: @Ikshvaku, If you want to understand apaurusheya and nitya, have a look at Emperumanar’s Vedartha Sangraha, especially verse 231

Comment: I've read it before and I understand the traditional argument for the Vedas being apaurusheya, but I don't think the argument holds up to scrutiny.

Comment: For old vs new hymns, this article is good, as well as the author and his blog: https://talageri.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-recorded-history-of-indo-european.html